# Is it possible to create web components without using class?

Tags: javascript, web-component

If everything in JavaScript comes from the prototype, I would imagine there is some way to create web components without using class. I never found any article about it, I don't know if it's because it's a bad practice or because it's not possible.

Comment: What do you refer to with *class*? JavaScript `class`, HTML `class` attribute?

Comment: Use of class in Javascript. Sorry, I expressed myself badly in the post, but I've corrected it.

Comment: `class` is just extra syntax in JavaScript. You can always do without. So what then is the question?

Comment: To create a web component, you usually use class, but I want to know how it can be created using just functions

Comment: Sure, like I wrote, you can write old-style JavaScript code. Web components were written also before the `class` syntax even existed in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? i searched a lot but i didn't find any web component created without using class

Comment: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhA9gWwA7IHYFMsBdocAPfPAExgAkAVWAGQFEQdU9CBvAKGmmG1zAy5RGBAgARmGABrABQBKaN1698ACwCWEAHSasuAE60G0ALzQABgB51ARgB8VHOOTQA7skMhy1gPT2DpYA3DzQAL5ckarQXMAArhD4aMys7LrkOABm+jhyAOSo8AC0-BjY7PkANHBIaJi4BArBQA)

Comment: In this case, class is still being used, I just want to use functions.

Comment: look on the right side, no class used, that's what your be dealing with.. no reason not to not use a class

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you have the example without using a class. I didn't know it would take so much work to create just with functions

Comment: It doesn't take as much as it's showing. The transpiler is just being extra careful to faithfully mimic classes as closely as possible, including edge cases. For most cases, you just need the constructor function (`function MyComponent() { /*etc*/`) and the prototype properties (`MyComponent.prototype.connectedCallback = function () { /*etc*/`)

Comment: In javascript a class is just a function that you call with the `new` keyword. Traditionally they are called **constructors**. So a class is simply a constructor (not to be confused with the `constructor` keyword in class syntax). Traditionally creating a constructor function requires you to define methods in a prototype (either an instance of another class or an object literal) then attach the prototype to the constructor function (your class). The new class syntax makes writing classes/constructor functions simpler by taking care of all the prototype stuff for you...

Comment: ... unfortunately the web component API does not expose a functional interface. The only way to create a web component is to supply a class to the CustomElementRegistry. It doesn't really care if you use the class syntax or if you created a constructor function the old-school way. It just need a function that it can call with the `new` keyword every time it needs to create a new element...

Comment: ... this is a common phenomena in javascript development. Most javascript programmers (and I'm deliberately not including Typescript programmers) are much more comfortable with functional style but the people who actually develop javascript implement javascript in C/C++. Therefore, every time they try to improve the language they create features from the point of view of an OO programmer - which generally tend to not match the way most javascript programmers think...

Comment: ... However, there are excellent frameworks out there written from the point of view of javascript programmers. Check out vue.js and svelte for examples of really good component systems that work the way javascript programmers think: using simple functions instead of doing stuff the OO-way. You may even want to look at React.js and it's functional component API.

Comment: There are some outdated docs, originally from html5rocks, on https://web.dev/customelements/. Apart from the spec update for custom elements v0, the object notation could be what you are searching for

Comment: @slebetman ... The usage of classes is not a criteria which defines an OO language. The usage of functions, especially when mentioning contexts like react/vue/svelte does not make one use a _"… functional style …"_, but a programming style based on functions. **Functional** starts with the usage of higher order functions. Why am'I nitpicking? Because precise wording matters, especially when it comes to comments like above, where the argumentation is close to "we/ours versus theirs". And whatever your preferred JS programming style is, it most probably fulfills more criteria of OOP than of FP.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can be done without using the `class` syntax. The trick is to use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) to substitute the call to `super`. Here's a small example snippet, containing a factory (`createCustomElementFactory`) to create the 'class' you need for registering a custom element using `customElements.define`.

To play with a (way more evolved) module for this, see/fork this [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kasjrz?file=Src%2FWebComponentFactory.js).

```js
const myCustomElementCreator = createCustomElementFactory();
const connectedCallback = function() {
  const isCustom = this.getAttribute(`is`);

  if (!isCustom) {
    this.style.display = `block`;
    this.style.padding = `2px 5px`;
    this.style.border = `1px solid #999`;
  }

  this.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, `<div>I am <i>&lt;${
    this.tagName.toLowerCase()}${
      isCustom ? ` is="${isCustom}"` : ``}></i></div>`);

  console.log(`We just connected the ${
    isCustom ? `custom` : `autonomous`} element '${
      this.tagName.toLowerCase()}${isCustom ? `[is="${isCustom}"]` : ``}'`);
};
const myBrandNewElemClass = myCustomElementCreator({ connectedCallback } );
const myBrandNewParagraphClass = myCustomElementCreator({
  connectedCallback,
  forElem: HTMLParagraphElement }); 

// register 2 elements
customElements.define( "my-brand-new-element", myBrandNewElemClass );

customElements.define( 
  "my-brand-new-paragraph", 
  myBrandNewParagraphClass,
  { extends: `p` } );

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, 
  `<my-brand-new-element>Hello world!</my-brand-new-element>`
);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, 
  `<p is="my-brand-new-paragraph">Hello paragraph!</p>`
);

function createCustomElementFactory() {
  const paramsPlaceholder = ({
    get all() {
      return {
        connectedCallback, 
        disconnectedCallback, 
        adoptedCallback, 
        attributeChangedCallback,
        observedAttributes, 
        forElem } = {}
    }
  });

  function CustomElementConstructorFactory(params = paramsPlaceholder.all) {
    const elemProto = params.forElem?.prototype instanceof HTMLElement 
      ? params.forElem : HTMLElement;
      
    function CustomElementConstructor() {
      if (elemProto !== HTMLElement) {
        self = Reflect.construct( params.forElem, [], CustomElementConstructor );
        return self;
      }

      return Reflect.construct( HTMLElement, [], CustomElementConstructor );
    }

    CustomElementConstructor.prototype = elemProto.prototype;
    CustomElementConstructor.observedAttributes = params.observedAttributes;

    Object.entries( params ).forEach( ([name, cb]) => { 
      if (cb && cb instanceof Function) { 
        CustomElementConstructor.prototype[name] = cb; } 
      } );

    return CustomElementConstructor;
  }

  return (params = paramsPlaceholder.all) => CustomElementConstructorFactory(params);
  }
```

Comment: This is indeed a good answer that does what it says. I didn't even think it was possible and was proven wrong, so very interesting...